# Letter spacing in Inkscape for the sequence fl

Tags: inkscape

The letter combination *fl* does not space in Inkscape.  I've set the letter spacing to 30 in the pictured case, and as can be seen the *fl* in *flying* is not spacing out.  Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inkscape allows you to turn ligatures off (explanation for what they are is in the post by @user287001)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for showing the click Apply part!  Ended up being very important :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a guess: fl is a ligature, a special character which contains f and l together.Many fonts have them.  I do not try to guess the exact method how you did pick it.

Here's a part of Arial's special characters, in the beginning of the list there's fi and fl

[image]

Advanced typesetting software can place ligatures automatically for nice looks instead of separate letters if that's specified in settings, but they also can take them off if there's a forced letter spacing. Inkscape isn't such program although very useful for many purposes.